# Handling multiple dialog windows with async tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

From my main WinForm application window, I want to simultaneously open multiple modeless dialogs. When all dialog windows are opened, I will raise some events and the event handlers on individual open dialogs are supposed to take necessary actions on those events. Since user wants access to the main form all the time, I cannot open these windows as modal dialogs.

I have written following code.

With this code, the dialog windows are opened but they are immediately closed too. What's wrong with the code? Why windows don't remain open?

```
private async void buttonOpenWindows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Task[] tasks = new Task[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateWindow),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateWindow),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateWindow),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateWindow)
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        // Raise necessary events when all windows are loaded.              
}

private async Task CreateWindow()
{
    // A refernce to main form is passed to the Window because all Windows will be subsribing to some events raised by the main form.
    var window = new Window1(this);
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `Task.Factory.StartNew` at all, just use `CreateWindow()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Thanks. May I know why usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew` is incorrect and why it does not keep the windows open?

Comment: An explanation of why windows are closed is in my answer. Why not use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, can be found in the `Remarks` section of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Are you *sure* async / await is the right tool for this job?  I'm not seeing anything in your description of the feature you are implementing would require it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is happening:**

```
private async Task CreateWindow()
{
    // A refernce to main form is passed to the Window because all Windows will be subsribing to some events raised by the main form.
    var window = new Window1(this);
    window.Show();
}
```

This creates a new window, owned by the first available thread in the system. As there is no more blocking code to run, the `Task` finishes successfully, and so the `Window` is closed/disposed.

If you want the `Window` to continue to be opened, you need to open it in your main thread.

Not sure what you are expecting to benefit from by opening the `Windows` in an `async` manner, though.

Comment: For others, actual code fix is mentioned in the Camilo's comment under my question. To make the code work, I had to call just `CreateWindow()`, without using `Task.Factory.StartNew`.